# Read JSON values from appvariables in asp.net core when JSON nodes are different at each level

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-core, configuration-files

I have the sample JSON below which I had provided in appvariables.json file.

```
{   "**Desc1**":
    {
        "Code": "Cd1",
        "Description": "Desc1"
      }
      "**Desc2**":
      {
       "Code": "Cd2",
        "Description": "Desc2"
      }
}
```

If this had been a JSON with same node Name(hightlighted Desc1,Desc2), creating a class and reading this would have been easier for me.

Could you please suggest on how this could be handled.

As this requires a dynamic way of handling, I could n't create a class.

I would want to read the JSON as it is from appvariables. Is there a way to achieve that in? Or please suggest better way of handling it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to read variables from `appvariables.json` file and bind the value with the following class :

```
public class Desc
{
    public string Code {get;set;}
    public string Description {get;set;}
}
```

simply use the `ConfigurationBuilder()` :

```
var config= new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("appvariables.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
    .Build();
var v1=config.GetSection("Desc1").Get<Desc>();
var v2=config.GetSection("Desc2").Get<Desc>();
```

**Edit**

to retrieve multiple `Desc` , you can use `GetChildren()`:

```
var v= config.GetChildren()
    .Select(i=>i.Get<Desc>());

foreach(var i in v){
    Console.WriteLine($"Got a variable : {i.Code}---{i.Description}");
}
```

**Edit2**

You can also add a `Where` condition to filter configurations as you like :

```
var v= config.GetChildren()
    .Where(i=>i.Key.StartsWith("Type"))
    .Select(i=>i.Get<Desc>());
```

Comment: The sample I had mentioned has 2 props. In general there will be more than 15. And the similar scenario will occur for many such JSONs. Is there any other way of doing it

Comment: what do you mean by "2 props"?  Are you saying there're multiple "Desc1" , "Desc2" ,"Desc3" .. ."Desc15" ? If so , why not use a loop to get the value ?

Comment: Yes.. I wanted to do exactly that.. But for going through the loop I want to know the number of such independents elements available,Which I'll get if I get could read JSON as a whole as it. Is it possible.?

Comment: @shakthi do you know the section names ?  How are they named ?

Comment: Section Name would be like "Type1","Type2" for each json

Comment: @shakthi Not a problem :)